# davfs2: /sbin/mount.davfs: different URL in /etc/fstab

Tags: mount, fstab, webdav, davfs2

I am trying to mount a webdav server in /etc/fstab with davfs, but when i try open this in my file manager (Thunar) i will get the error:

```
Failed to mount "My Folder"

/sbin/mount.davfs: different URL in /etc/fstab
```

The entry in /etc/fstab looks like this:

```
http://<server_url>/my/path/Doe\054\040John/  /home/john/My\040Folder       davfs   user,noauto     0       0
```

But i am still able to mount it successfully with:

```
sudo mount -t davfs http://<server-url>/my/path/Doe,\ John/ /home/john/My\ Folder
```

Any ideas what am i doing wrong in /etc/fstab?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: please give feedback of the output of "mount" and what exactly is output on "sudo mount /home/john/My\040Folder"

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR** aka the fun part:

In the `/etc/fstab` file, you should **NOT** escape the **comma** character while spaces and tabs must be escaped using zero-padded octal numbers preceded by backslash `\` as it stated in fstab's man page. In your case, the URL string should look like this:

```
http://<server_url>/my/path/Doe,\040John/
```

**The boring part:**

First of all, you should take a look at this one:
https://superuser.com/a/527503/938480

I'll cite the last sentence of the post above here which is essential for the answer in my opinion:

> Note that, while code points are supported **for other characters as
> well, the support is rather flaky**. On my machine, you can write \127
> instead of W, but not \070 instead of 8...

And the davfs2 man states:

> URLS AND MOUNT POINTS WITH SPACES Special characters like spaces in
> pathnames are a mess. They are interpreted differently by different
> programs and protocols, and there are different rules for escaping. In
> fstab spaces must be replaced by a three digit octal escape sequence.
> Write [http://foo.bar/path\040with\040spaces](http://foo.bar/path%5C040with%5C040spaces) instead of
> http://foo.bar/path with spaces. For the davfs2.conf and the secrets
> files please see the escape and quotation rules described in the
> davfs2.conf(5) man page. On command line you must obey the escaping
> rules of the shell.

And finally let's look at the fstab manual itself:

> The second field (fs_file).
> This field describes the mount point for the filesystem.
> For swap partitions, this field should be specified as 'none'.
> If the name of the mount point contains spaces these can be escaped as '\040'

As we can see above, there is actually no mentioning of anything but spaces and tabs.

I've tested the issue with one of the free online Nextcloud instances (Nextcloud natively comes with a built-in WevDAV support) and I got the same error using the same folder name as in your example `Doe, John` and the same escaping sequence `\054\040`. Then I removed escaping of the comma and it mounted ok.

Answer (score 1):

Too few information to give a hint on whats going wrong here - but after installing **davfs2** my working fstab entry looks like this:

```
https://my-owncloud-url/remote.php/webdav  /media/owncloud/ davfs user,noauto,rw,_netdev 0 0
```

works very well...
just after changing the content of the fstab you can check if it is working by entering

```
sudo mount -a
```

or by entering

```
sudo mount mountpoint-here
```

but keep in mind - the folder has to exist before mount can be initialized...